# How two ItemSources can be bound to a ListBox item?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I have a case,

```
    public class dictLanguage
    {
        public string EnglishText { get; set; }
        public string FinnishText { get; set; }
    }

    IEnumerable<dictLanguage> result1 = from ....select new dictLanguage{ EnglishText=... };
    IEnumerable<dictLanguage> result2 = from ....select new dictLanguage{ FinnishText=... };

    LstBox.DataContext = result1
```

In Xaml, I have

```
<listbox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  ...
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding EnglishText}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding FinnishText}">
  ...
</listbox>
```

I am reading English text from one  xml file into "result1" and Finnish text from another xml file into "result2", but I can set only one ItemSource to ListBox. I have tried hard, but can't find out any solution. I want to display both values of "dictLanguage", which are being taken from two different XML files.

Looking for ANY solution,

- Either I can merge **result1** and **result2**
- Or, Read the two xml files simultaneouly, which Iamunable toread using "from...select" clause
- Or, Binding both, **result1** and **result2** to the listbox
- Or, any possible, and better solution

Could anyone tell me the solution please? - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind two ItemsSources to a ListBox. Correct and easy way would be to combine data from 2 xml files into one object set (containing all translations). You can write:

```
from englishText in xml1
from finnishText in xml2
select new DictLanguage() { EnglishText = englishText, FinnishText = finnishText };
```

Please, read this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513866.aspx) on more info for combining multiple sources.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I spent my whole day in solving this problem through several different ways, and it was this easy :).

Comment: BTW, why did you vote this question down, just curious to know and to learn if I have done something wrong?

Comment: Well, unfortunately this solution is not working well, it is working in a loop, like it takes one sentence from "enlishText" and takes all the sentences from "finnishText", then second sentence from englishtext and then all the sentences from finnishText..and so on.

Comment: You could try and synchronize them by line number.

Comment: `from a in xml1...from b in xml2... where a.index==b.index` I solved the problem something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could union your two lists together to create one items source:

```
IEnumerable<dictLanguage> result1;
IEnumerable<dictLanguage> result2;
//populate collections....
IEnumerable<dictLanguage> allResults = result1.Union(result2);
```

Comment: This is the answer of another question/problem of mine, many thanks!:)

Comment: Not working, unfortunately. It only shows the contents of result1, when I switch result1 with result2, like result2.Contact(result1), then it shows contents of result2.

Comment: It has appended the results, but not combined (or merged) the results.

Comment: I see, you want only the union set of both lists, is that correct? Please see my updated answer along with this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx